# Easy to GM Harry Potter RPG

Tags: game-recommendation, new-gm

I have a friend who's not very interested in playing RPGs, but he's a Harry Potter nut. Is there a decent (probably fan-made, I've heard that an official HPRPG is unlikely) system that is easy for a new GM and is either specifically for the Harry Potter universe, or from a general RPG system that can be played as-is in a Harry Potter setting?

**Note:** When I say 'easy for a new GM', the game would ideally have between 20 and 100 pages. Shorter is better, but if something is too rules-lite it becomes unplayable, especially for someone with no GM experience. I also want the system to capture at least part of the feel of the magic in the books.

Comment: I had some friends who used Dresden Files, but they did the conversion themselves. They made their own magical school with new characters, set in the same world. I'm not sure I'd call DF easy to GM, though.

Comment: Not sure whether to make this an answer, as I have no actual experience with it, but have you looked at http://www.memento-mori.com/other/games/broomstix_rpg.pdf?

Comment: @Phil I have, and it's not complete as a game. It's at most 5 pages of pdf if it weren't spread out so far. It's a nice idea for a game, there's just not enough.

Comment: As this is a [tag:game-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and the guidance on recommendation questions on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: Apparently no one reads our game-rec guidance.  Sorry, the way we prevent recommendation questions on this site from degenerating into the "my favorite system is" noise found on forums is to focus on answers that have specifically done what they are asking about.  Most of the answers here don't indicate any actual attempts at doing it and just recommend "good systems" and thus I am deleting them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are least two fan-made Harry Potter RPGs: [Harry Potter RPG](http://meetthenewboss.info/kent/hogwarts/Harry%20Potter%20RPG%20Core%20Rule%20Book.pdf) by Matthew Kearns and [Broomstix](http://www.memento-mori.com/other/games/broomstix_rpg.pdf) by Jared Sorensen.

None of them are very complex in terms of rules but the latter is really simple (16 pages Broomstix vs 163 pages Harry Potter RPG) so it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I suggested Broomstix in the comments to the original question, and it was rejected :o)

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen it. 0:-) I hope the OP will benefit from Harry Potter RPG (or any other better answer).